# cannot communicate with function. Function invocation was interrupted. in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a cloud function running in GCP with Firebase. The function is very simple and storing some data in Firestore.

I see in the logs the following error: 
`Error: cannot communicate with function. Function invocation was interrupted.`

It happens in less than 1% of the requests, but I can't understand why they're happening.

Comment: see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/125425924.
Some people (including me) have same issue and engineers in GCP are investigating now.

Comment: Please don't post questions that are asking about service issues to Stack Overflow.  Contact Firebase support directly instead so they can collect information from you.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: So, is this an issue that should be solved somehow on the developer's side, e.g. by enabling retries, or this is a bug that would be solved by the Google engineering team and would no longer be expected in the future?

Comment: @Yulian I have the same issue. Did you find a solution to this log error?

Comment: I'm thinking at adding more pub/sub or tasks to enforce better retry mechanisms. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: @AngularM, no just follow the issue tracker, as stated by jun: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/125425924

Comment: Hi, could you find exact reason for why function invocation interrupted. I have no access to follow the mentioned issue link. Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 13):

When people (@doug-stevenson) are tempted to answer that we shouldn't be asking service questions, please remember that we're posting here because we don't know that. We assume it is an error in our code or configuration.